# How to find Recycler view position in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have on `vertical` `Recyclerview` and inside each row one `horizontal` `Recyclerview`.
I am using this structure for category product listing.

now there is one API (Lets say API-1) which is giving me list of category, and i am getting category id in that api (API-1),

From that categoryid i have to call another API (Lets say API-2) which will give me product list, 
and that product list will be displayed in `horizontal` `ListView`.

Now this API-2 is having pagination, so after displaying 10 product i have to call api again for more products.

and for that i m gonna need category id once again. so im not able to find the category id when i'm scrolling `horizontal` `Recyclerview`,
the position of `vertical` `Recyclerview`is have the category id i want to use.

so is there any solution?

Comment: Store variable in the horizontal array data, that will indicate current category id. You can setup this after loading category list. Also it will be nice to see part of your code

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to hold a map of Integer -> String and store each category with it's position when the view is being created inside the adapter.

Later, query the map to get the right CategoryId by position.